# Python, find a word and the location of each character in that word in a string

Tags: python, string

Let's say in Python I have this sentence:

```
my_sentence = "I like to drive my car around the round block twice daily"
```

And I want to find the word 'round' in this sentence. I know I can use `find, index, rfind`, and `rindex`like so:

```
print my_sentence.find('round')
>>>24
```

What I want to do is find the location of each letter in 'round' within the sentence and only use the first occurrence of the word 'round'. I would like it to print out the location of each letter of 'round' within the string. I've tried to do this (for example, finding the last letter and going from there):

```
last_letter = my_sentence.find('round')
last_letter2 = last_letter[-1::]
```

This produces an error. So, what's the best way of getting the location of each letter of a word that exists in a string? I'm new to Python and I saw there was ways to find where a word was, but not each letter of the word in the string. How do I do this?
Expected output in parenthesis:

```
r (location 24) o (25) u (26) n(27) d(28)
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: `last_letter` is an `int`. You cannot use indexing on `int`s, hence the error: `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`. `last_letter2` is just `last_letter+`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: Just find the first occurrence of the word, then add offsets for the letters.

```
>>> my_sentence = "I like to drive my car around the round block twice daily"
>>> word = 'round'
>>> pos = my_sentence.find(word)
>>> [(c, pos + i) for (i, c) in enumerate(word)]
[('r', 24), ('o', 25), ('u', 26), ('n', 27), ('d', 28)]
```

Comment: This will give very strange results for where `word` is not found in `my_sentence`. Also - you can take advantage of the `start` argument for `enumerate` so you don't have to do `pos + i`.

Answer (score 2):

Write a helper function, eg:

```
def my_find(sentence, what):
    try:
        start = sentence.index(what)
        return [(ch, idx) for idx, ch in enumerate(what, start)]
    except ValueError:
        return []
```

Example:

```
>>> my_find("I like to drive my car around the round block twice daily", "round")
[('r', 24), ('o', 25), ('u', 26), ('n', 27), ('d', 28)]
>>> my_find("I like to drive my car around the round block twice daily", "xyz")
[]
```

**Note: this handles cases where `word` is not in `my_sentence` in a sane way - the other answers will give surprising results...**